# How can I show the namespace in my .NET 6 console application?

Tags: .net, .net-6.0

I created a console application on .NET 6 and I can't show my namespace name anywhere.

I need to show my namespace.
How can I show the namespace in my .NET 6 console application?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "show"? Print to console?

Comment: I just want to see the namespace in my file.

Comment: What does `I just want to see the namespace in my console` mean? You want to print the namespace to the console with `Console.WriteLine` ? You want the namespace to appear as a `namespace` clause at the top? You want to use a specific namespace? You want to find out what the default namespace is called?

Comment: Sorry, I want to see the namespace in my file.

Comment: You're repeating the same phrase with different wording. What does `I want to see the namespace in my file.` mean? You want to see a `namespace MyProgramNamespace;` at the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating project you should check "Do not use top-level statements".

[image: This]

results in:

[image: Result]

Comment: That's throwing out the baby with the bathwater. You can have namespaces with top-level statements

Comment: That works my friend

Comment: @Takitaha what works? For what? That's not what you asked at all. You can specify the namespace you want with top level statements